# using new Date () in typescript throws an error: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function that wants to handle timestamp, which particularly includes this line that's using a Date() constructor.

```
function CreateDate(){
    const d = new Date('2022-08-02T04:10:23.542Z')

    // the rest of function
}
```

I'm really not sure why TypeScript kept throwing a TypeError at this usage of Date() constructor?

I've tried to declare an interface Date before the function, such as below but it doesn't work.

```
interface DateConstructor {
  new (): Date;
  new (value: string): Date;
}

function CreateDate(){
    const d = new Date('1231')

    // the rest of function
}
```

---

Update:
Some comment pointed out that this is not replicable in typescript IDE. I've tried this on another codebase (only React & TypeScript) and it turns out fine there.

Comparing the non-working and working environment, I found that the type `Date` being used in nonworking environment is described as

```
const Date: StyledComponent<"div", any, {}, never>
```

while in the working environment its taking the `Date` type from typescript well:

```
var Date: DateConstructor
new (value: string | number | Date) => Date (+4 overloads)
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this, it looks fine to me in a standalone IDE](https://tsplay.dev/Wz5ZLm).  Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue to others; if you can't do that, then you'll have to start providing more details about your local environment, because that's where the issue is likely to be.

Comment: Not reproducible in TS playground on 4.7.4: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAYQE4FMCGV0BFvoAUAlAN4BQiViECAzlIgCaIC8iY6A7ovjoQHIATAAYhQgLQiAHFKEAVEQBYAXAEYRKoQGYAdAFYlQgFoDilagHpLiKAAt0iDA0RxgiUJFgJyAXyA

Comment: Did you import `Date` from somewhere ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler No i didn't import the date.

Comment: @jcalz It seems to be my local environment, since I tried to replicate this in another repository and it works fine. 

Comparing the non-working and working environment, I found that the type `Date` being used in nonworking environment is described as 

`const Date: StyledComponent<"div", any, {}, never>`

while in the working environment its taking the `Date` type from typescript well:
`var Date: DateConstructor`
`new (value: string | number | Date) => Date (+4 overloads)`

Comment: Looks like someone redefined `Date` in your environment?  `StyledComponent<"div", any, {}, never>` is some third party type and you should track it down.  Should we close this question as not reproducible?

Comment: Just an update, I found it works when I use `new Date()` in a separate .ts file that doesn't utilise styled-components. Thankyou guys for your helps in figuring this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem and was due to a component with the same name, ie. `<Date />`